# How to fetch count of every classid from DB table in Mysql see below for detail

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have this table structure

```
| id | classid | contextid |
----------------------------
  1       2           2
  2       3           1
  3       2           1
  4       3           1
  5       1           2
  5       1           4
```

How to fetch count of every classid from DB table in Mysql I need a select query for it?

Comment: @Answerers Thanks For Answering I just felt like chosing Jignesh's Answer as he is at the lowest score among all, no Offense... Thanks For your Time

Comment: Of course it's your choice to make, but you don't choose someone because of their score. You choose someone, because they gave the best solution the first. Your choice counts for other's who have the same problem as well. Thus, I believe John Green's answer is the one you should pick, because it was the first answer, and it provides an alias for the counter.

Comment: Some People are Overpractical In Life, Rather Than Motivating Someone....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT classid, COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY classid;
```

Answer (score 4):

Count of every classid... do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT classid, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM tbl_name GROUP BY classid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT classid, COUNT(classid) classid_count FROM table_name GROUP BY classid;
```